# am building a color-palette-app using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router

1. but the thing is when i am setting up the routes i want that my palette change dynamically as the path='/palette/:id'.
2. i want this id to be fetched in parent itself because i wanna use it in a function which fetch the matching palette and return it as a prop to the element={}

I get the id in my child component(Palette.js) BY using useParams() hook, but as i mentioned i want it in the parent(App.js).
Secondly, i tried a state colorId in parent and pass its function setColorId in child to set it but not working.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqilL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMhVC.png)

Comment: Please [edit] to post actual code snippets instead of images of code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I known, you can try to put `setColorId` to a `useEffect`:

```
// other imports
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const Pattle = props => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  // other code

  // run setColorId every time id change
  useEffect(() => {
    setColorId(id)
  }, [setColorId, id]);
}
```